# How to set location in Google Sky

Tags: google-sky

On my Android phone, Google Sky uses GPS to figure out where I am at.  But when I am using the web version, I can't figure out how to set my location.  For what I'm trying to do my phone screen isn't sufficient and I need to use the web version.

How do I set my location and tell it which direction (e.g. South) I want to look in?  I tried entering my latitude and longitude in the search bar but it is only suggesting a constellation.  The [help](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/91511) link does not tell me.

Comment: @pnuts this is google sky, not google maps.  are you saying i have to permit google maps to see my location and google sky will then know it automatically?  i'll try this...

Comment: @pnut ah ok.  i checked what sites were blocked and allowed to see my location, made sure Google was allowed, then got maps to ask to see my location, granted it permission, reloaded, Sky, and... still nothing